# jquery animate create zoomOut effect with squarish rectangle shaped image to fit window width or height and maintain aspect

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate, zooming

OFF the bat: scale() is not a working option.

How can i dynamically animate my image which has a width or height of 700% back to the original css width auto and or height auto from the information below.

My image ( .backone > img ) has the following actual || real dimensions:

1024px width
570px height

my CSS for the image is as follows:

```
/*this is the same as the window width and height*/
.backone {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
z-index: 6;
position: absolute;
left: 0;
top: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
}

/** the original CSS dimensions **/
.backone > img {
position: absolute;
width: auto;
height: auto;
min-height: 100%;
min-width: 100%;
left: 50%;
top: 0px;
bottom: auto;
transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

During the course of the script i added either a height of 700% or a width of 700% to the .backone > img ( while it was hidden ) depending on if the width of the window is greater then height, or not.

Now, when the image shows, i want to animate it back to the "original css" dimensions as above.

What i have tried:

- to capture the width and height of the image before adding the 700% width || height, this did not work because the image was hidden and hadn't reached the DOM yet.
- css animation, but this restricted me to returning the width or height back to 100%, and distorted the image.
- several attempts with jQuery animate to get the correct dimensions, but i can get the calculations correct.

What calculations can i use for this to return the image to its original dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:
I looked at this problem wrong, I tried to get the width of the image at 700% width or 700% height and then work out the calculation back to the original screen width or height.

All i had to do was just take the original image and calculate the ratio to fit the screen.

```
    function getImgdimes() {
        var w = $(window).outerWidth();
        var h = $(window).outerHeight();
        var iw = 1024; // original image width
        var ih = 570;  // original image height
        var diff = iw / w;
        if ((ih / diff) < h) {
            var nw = iw / (ih / h);
            var nh = h;
            $('div.backone img').css('height', '700%');
        } else {
            var nw = w;
            var h = ih / diff;
            $('div.backone img').css('width', '700%');
        }
        var m = [nh, nw];
        return m;
    }

    the animate function uses the m array values m[0] and m[1]
```

can be viewed here: https://ironman-suit.com